# Python program to find prime numbers (3.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program that finds prime numbers. The user is asked to provide a number greater than 2 (n) the program then makes a list starting at 2 and ending at the user's number (n). In my program, I am supposed to set a variable called current to 2 and then loop through the list looking for multiples of current and removing them. At the end of a loop I add 1 to current and the program loops again doing the same as before. The list is printed each time. My program works correctly (I am testing by using the number 10 as n) when it gets to the end 10 is left even though it should have been removed. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    global n
    n = int ( input ( "Please enter a number larger than 2. " ) )
    if n > 2:
        break
    else:
        print ( "Your number is not larger than 2." )
        continue

current = 2
myList = list ( range ( 2, n + 1 ) )
while current < n:
    if current == []:
        break
    for i in reversed ( range ( len( myList )-1 ) ):
        if myList[i] % current == 0 and myList[i] != current and ( myList[i] / current ).is_integer(): myList.pop(i)
        print ( myList )
    current = current + 1
```

Comment: That seems like a wildly convoluted way to find a prime number.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono This is a pretty common homework prompt.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @TemporalWolf Oh. I didn't know that. I was going to say, square root and check is decidedly easier. But if it's homework and must be done this way then that's that.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm just learning to program and this is for an assignment. I don't get an error it just doesn't remove the final number in the list when it is a multiple of the variable current.

Comment: @mjruss in the future, please include a comment in your original post saying it's for an assignment/homework. People are more likely to explain themselves when you do, which will improve your understanding! And welcome to [so]!

Comment: @TemporalWolf Thank you! That fixed that problem. The only other issue I am having is once the prime numbers are found the program continues looping over 20 times printing the same numbers. Any idea on how to stop this?

Comment: @mjruss that's because you've asked it to print every time it does a step. Those are all the steps it's doing verifying that the rest of the numbers aren't prime.

Comment: @mjruss I updated my answer with a solution to that issue as well.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Ok that makes sense. Would it be possible to limit the number of times it prints based on the amount of numbers in the list?

Comment: @TemporalWolf Awesome! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mjruss Don't forget to hit the checkmark to accept the answer if it helped you. As I mentioned above, in the future please acknowledge it's a homework question: It will usually improve the responses you receive.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I'll do that next time. Since I'm new here I can check it but won't show that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for i in reversed ( range ( len( myList )-1 ) ):` should be 
`for i in reversed ( range ( len( myList ) ) ):`

range by default doesn't include the last number: `range(5)` gives `0,1,2,3,4`

To make it only output a line when it makes a change:

```
if myList[i] % current == 0 and myList[i] != current and ( myList[i] / current ).is_integer():
    myList.pop(i)
    print ( myList )
```

If you do the print inside the if statement, then only when it makes a change will it display the new list.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" loop has the problem. Remove the "-1" and you should be fine, since range is inclusive, exclusive. Just a note, when looking for primes within a range(2,n) you don't have to check to n, just to sqrt(n). Check this link.
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-first-find-the-prime-numbers-up-to-square-root-of-N-in-segmented-sieve